# Failed to call a service with Retrofit via VPN

Tags: android, android-studio, retrofit, retrofit2

I´m trying to call a Rest service with Retrofit via VPN. First I connect to the VPN in my computer, after I run the app in a emulator and call the rest service, but retrofit failed to connect, with this message:

> Failed to connect to /100.100.100.100:8080

Is there anyway to to set vpn configuration on Retrofit? Thanks.

This is my client

```
 private val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .connectTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .readTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .build()


private var retrofit: Retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .build()
```

Comment: have you tried `adb reverse tcp:8080 tcp:8080` ?

Comment: Yes, but didnt work.

Comment: I am also stuck in this issue as of today :( Any solutions to this so far ??

Comment: I am stuck in same problem, did you find the solution?